# Directory not found while installing gtest library

Tags: googletest, xcode8, macos-sierra

I'm installing google test to use with Xcode, but I'm running into a small problem. When installing the headers and libs on my system it is recommended to use the following commands

```
$ sudo cp -a include/gtest /usr/include
$ sudo cp -a lib/.libs/* /usr/lib/
```

However, I am getting this error

```
cp: include/gtest: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to properly install the files after I've built them?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you are referring to are wrong and outdated. The hidden `.libs` directory comes from when gtest was built with autotools. I suggest the following:

Get the latest version, 1.8, from the current gtest/gmock repository at https://github.com/google/googletest.

Read https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md for how to build with cmake.

Specify the install prefix with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` on the command-line, or use `cmake-gui` for a more friendly experience. Do not install anything below `/usr/` (it is a system path); I suggest installing below `/usr/local/` or, even better, to install locally for each project that needs gtest, for example in the same build directory of the project.